# How to start and App Chooser

Tags: android

The task of this application is to implicitly activate a separate application to view the URL, “http:// www.google.com”. So, App Chooser should appear and let me choose between at least two browsers: the default one, which will show me the www.google.com site, and another simple "browser", which just shows me the url. **The problem is - App chooser doesn't appear, when i use implicit activity.** Probably I wrote wrong intent filters for second "simple browser".

```
private void startImplicitActivation() {

    Log.i(TAG, "Entered startImplicitActivation()");

    // TODO - Create a base intent for viewing a URL 
    // (HINT:  second parameter uses parse() from the Uri class)
    Uri adress = Uri.parse(URL);
    Intent intentUrlView = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, adress);

    // TODO - Create a chooser intent, for choosing which Activity
    // will carry out the baseIntent. Store the Intent in the 
    // chooserIntent variable below. HINT: using the Intent class' 
    // createChooser())
    Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(intentUrlView, CHOOSER_TEXT);
    //chooserIntent = null;

    Log.i(TAG,"Chooser Intent Action:" + chooserIntent.getAction());
    // TODO - Start the chooser Activity, using the chooser intent
    if (intentUrlView.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(chooserIntent);
    }
}
```

**MANIFEST**

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="course.labs.intentslab.mybrowser"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="13"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MyBrowserActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <!-- TODO - Add necessary intent filter information so that this
                            Activity will accept Intents with the 
                            action "android.intent.action.VIEW" and with an "http" 
                            schemed URL -->
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <data android:scheme="http" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Comment: So this is from the Maryland Android class part one on coursera...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seriously, you have a GUI editor for manifest.

This

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
<data android:scheme="http" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
```

should placed in `<intent-filter>` tag, as you already can see in your manifest.
Like this:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MyBrowserActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>

        <!-- TODO - Add necessary intent filter information so that this
                        Activity will accept Intents with the 
                        action "android.intent.action.VIEW" and with an "http" 
                        schemed URL -->
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <data android:scheme="http" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    </intent-filter>

</activity>
```

---

That is how it done in default browser:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
            <data android:scheme="about" />
            <data android:scheme="javascript" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
            <data android:scheme="inline" />
            <data android:scheme="file" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/html" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/xhtml+xml" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.wap.xhtml+xml" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: Thank you vety much! I haven't recognized such silly mistake beacause of tiredness. But still, even after that fix my programm doesnt work.

Comment: If you included category, all intents that match intent-filter **must** have this category set. Your code doesn't set required category, so your intent doesn't match with your filter. Read how intent filters work in docs

Comment: "The system will deliver an implicit intent to your app component only if the intent can pass through one of your intent filters." - http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/components/intents-filters.html As I understand, if an application passes and action intent filter, then it will apear in the App Chooser. But I deleted the category field, i looked through the documentation and i can't find the problem in the manifest file. Now I am sure that the problem is in that browser application. I have installed opera mini and chrome and i see the App chooser, containing them, but not that app.

Comment: Thanks! I just addead default category and it works now.

Comment: Explanation here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/category-element.html "In order to receive implicit intents, you must include the CATEGORY_DEFAULT category in the intent filter. The methods startActivity() and startActivityForResult() treat all intents as if they declared the CATEGORY_DEFAULT. If you do not declare it in your intent filter, no implicit intents will resolve to your activity."

Answer (score 18):

Seems like the Adam Porter's Third Week Assignment of **Programming mobile Application for Android HandHeld systems**. 
Anyway, I hope you have your solution
inside the AndroidManifest.xml you would need to add three more intent filters.

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<data android:scheme="http" />
```

Further, if you were not able to run the AndroidUnit tests,

make sure you have done something similar to this in the ActionListener of the implicit button call.

```
Intent baseIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        baseIntent.setData(Uri.parse(URL));

Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(baseIntent, "Select Application");
```

Coursera already has a mailing list. Please use that.

Comment: +1 for "Seems like the Adam Porter's Third Week Assignment of Programming mobile Application for Android HandHeld systems" :)

Answer (score 2):

Easy implementation of multiple actions app chooser:

```
Intent phoneCall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.fromParts("tel", contactNumber, null));
// Intent sms = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("sms:" + contactNumber));
Intent whatsapp = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse("smsto:" + contactNumber));
Uri.Builder builder = CalendarContract.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon();
builder.appendPath("time");
ContentUris.appendId(builder, Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());
Intent calendarIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(builder.build());

Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(whatsapp, "chooser??"); // default action
chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, new Intent[]{phoneCall, calendarIntent}); // additional actions
startActivity(chooser);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I am doing:

Step 1: First in the strings,

```
<string name="webklink">&lt;a href="http://www.google.com">SomeLink&lt;/a></string>
```

Step 2: My Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/webklink"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Step 3: Getting the link from the strings.

```
public class OpenWeb extends Activity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webopen);

        TextView someLink = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        if(someLink!=null){

            someLink.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
            someLink.setText(Html.fromHtml(getResources().getString(R.string.webklink)));
        }

    }
}
```

Hope this helps..:)

Comment: I don't understand why a down vote for the answer above. It's perfectly fine and it's working good as required per question. If someone is doing a downvote, there should be a reason explained in the comment box.

Answer (score 0):

You have to run `lab3a_MyBrowser` before you run `lab3a_IntentsLab`, so that the browser gets installed on your phone. Then it will be visible to your chooser.