# have andriod app prompt user what to use to open app every time

Tags: c#, android

User can only choose app once and then they are stuck with using that app to open files, how do i make so it prompt you everytime, im using xamarin and c#

```cs
StartActivity(new Intent(Intent.ActionView, FileProvider.GetUriForFile(Application.Context, Application.Context.PackageName + ".provider", new Java.IO.File("./" + currentFolder +"/" + curentfile))));
```

Comment: Try this PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).edit().clear().commit);

Comment: you can use `Intent.createChooser` to show the chooser every time. This question is about Java, but should be easy to convert to C#: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21800948/1568530

Comment: @Vladyslav Matviienko thanks, worked perfectly